# Calling a python program with c++

Tags: python, c++

I want to make a c++ program that will search for a href from a file and that href needs to be **scraped**. For that I am using python to scrape the data from href and save it in a file. Now my problem is how can I send the href to the python program?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164776/parameter-passing-from-python-script-to-c-with-boost-python

Answer (score 1):

You can execute command and let python interpreter to do the job.

```
int result = system("python_path python_file_path.py");
```

Or Boost has a library for that [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: The std::system statement is calling the host command processor which allows to execute terminal programs like “ls -l” but also python scripts like “python3 hello.py”. It would do the job, but it's a bad programming style. The more elaborated form of connecting C++ with a Python program is to use a formalized API which can be implemented with the REST framework.

Comment: Yes i agree with you this is why i added Boost api solution as well. I just wanted him to be aware of `system` funcion as well for non-api solution. Because if he executing a little python script in c++ program, `system` wouldn't be harm.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a c++ program that will search for a href from a file

(notice that you don't need python for that; you need to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) HTML; you'll find C++ libraries for that, such as [myhtml](https://github.com/lexborisov/myhtml)).

> Now my problem is how can I send the href to the python program?

This is [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) specific, and also specific to your Python program. Read [more](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) about C++. Be aware of [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)

Read the chapter about [embedding and extending python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/).

Consider also starting a new [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) and using [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facilities. On Linux, see [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).